# How to access value in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am having trouble pulling results out of an API that is returning JSON.

I've tried the below:

```
  print(json_normalize(json_data["meta"]))
```

returns:

```
                   currentPage     morePages  resultsPerPage
           0            2            True            2000
```

How do I access the value in morePages? I've tried:

```
    print(json_normalize(json_data["meta"][0]["morePages"]))
```

but that returns     KeyError 0

How do I go about pulling the morepages value out?

Comment: please share the json source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to normalize the json data. This should work.

```
json_data["meta"][0]["morePages"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try   `type(json_data["meta"])`
If the Output is a String and not Dict u can use `json.loads(json_data["meta"])` to convert this Content also into a dict.